# Javascript - Recursive looping while keeping track of parent child relationships

Tags: javascript, json, loops, underscore.js

Using Javascript *(Underscore is also a feasible solution to use)*, how can I loop through a complex JSON object (no array) that can go several objects deep.

How can I loop through the JSON object and keep track of which level in the parent/child hierarchy I am at?

For instance, I have the following JSON:

```
{
    'parent1': {
        'name': 'something',
        'children': {
            'name': 'something else'
        }
    },
    'parent2': {
        'name': 'something',
        'children': {
            'name': 'something else',
            'anotherProp': {
                'name': 'whoa..something else'
            }
        }
    },
}
```

Ultimately, I want to loop through and add a property called 'level' *(ex. parent1.level)*.  The top parent level is **0** and the next child level is **1**, etc.    The JSON is dynamic so there is no set structure, just that it's a complex parent/child JSON object.

I'm fine with a recursive function, but determining the relative level of each JSON key/val pair is tripping me atm.

Let me know if any more info is needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pass the level to the recursive function; decrement when you return. Pass 0 at the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simply recurse with a function that takes an object and level:

```js
var obj = {'parent1': {'name': 'something','children': {    'name': 'something else'}},'parent2': {'name': 'something','children': {'name': 'something else','anotherProp': { 'name': 'whoa..something else'}}},}

function recurse(obj, level=0){
    // add level
    obj.level = level
    Object.values(obj).map(v =>{
        if (typeof v === 'object') {
            // call again on children with increased level
            recurse(v, level+1)
        }
    })
}

recurse(obj)
console.log(obj)
```

If you didn't want this to be a recursive function, you could use a classic breadth-first search adding levels along the way. Something like:

```js
var obj = {'parent1': {'name': 'something','children': {    'name': 'something else'}},'parent2': {'name': 'something','children': {'name': 'something else','anotherProp': { 'name': 'whoa..something else'}}},}

function addLevel(obj){
    obj.level = 0
    // will be FIFO queue
    let queue = [obj]
    while(queue.length){
        let o = queue.shift();
        Object.values(o).forEach(item => {
            if (typeof item === 'object'){ 
                // level will be one more than parent
                item.level = o.level +1
                queue.push(item)
            }
        });
    }
}

addLevel(obj)
console.log(obj)
```

I'm not certain if your `level: 0` starts at the root of the object or first parent, but that's an easy adjustment. Both assume the original object is a tree (i.e. no circular references). If there are circular references, you would need to keep track of which objects you've seen.

Comment: Solved my issue.  Thank you!